# JS missing ) in parenthetical (line #88)

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, geogebra

I'm writing a program in JS for checking equal angles in GeoGebra.
This is my first JS code, I used c# formerly for game programming.
The code is:

```
var names = ggbApplet.getAllObjectNames();
var lines = new Set();
var angles = new Set();
var groups = new Set();
for(var i=0; i<names.length; i++)
{
if(getObjectType(names[i].e)==="line")
{
lines.add(names[i]);
}
}

for(var i=0;i<lines.size;i++)
{
for(var j=0;j<i;j++)
{

var angle = new Angle(i,j);
angles.add(angle);

}
}

for(var i=0;i<angles.size;i++)
{
    var thisVal = angles.get(i).value;
    var placed = false;
    for(var j=0;j<groups.size;j++)
    {
        if(groups.get(j).get(0).value===thisVal)
        {
        groups.get(j).add(angles.get(i));
        placed = true;
        }
    }
    if(!placed)
    {
    var newGroup = new Set();
    newGroup.add(angles.get(i));
    groups.add(newGroup);
    }
}

for(var i=0;i<groups.size;i++)
{
var list="";
for(var j=0;j<groups.get(i).size;j++)
{
list = list+groups.get(i).get(j).name;
if(j != groups.get(i).size-1)
{
list = list+",";
}
}
var comm1 = "Checkbox[angle_{"+groups.get(i).get(0).value+"},{"+list+"}]";
ggbApplet.evalCommand(comm1);
var comm2 = "SetValue[angle_{"+groups.get(i).get(0).value+"}+,0]";
ggbApplet.evalCommand(comm2);

}



(function Angle (i, j)
{
this.lineA = lines.get(i);
this.lineB = lines.get(j);

this.name = "angleA_"+i+"B_"+j;
var comm3 = "angleA_"+i+"B_"+j+" = Angle["+this.lineA+","+this.lineB+"]";
ggbApplet.evalCommand(comm3);
var val = ggbApplet.getValue(this.name);
if(val>180)
{val = val-180}
this.value = val;
ggbApplet.setVisible(name,false)
});

function Set {
var elm;
this.elements=elm;
this.size=0;
}

Set.prototype.get = new function(index)
{
return this.elements[index];
}

Set.prototype.add = new function(object)
{
this.elements[this.size]=object;
this.size = this.size+1;
}
```

It turned out that GeoGebra does not recognize Sets so I tried to make a Set function.
Basically it collects all lines into a set, calculates the angles between them, groups them and makes checkboxes to trigger visuals.

the GeoGebra functions can be called via ggbApplet and the original Workspace commands via ggbApplet.evalCommand(String) and the Workspace commands I used are the basic Checkbox, SetValue and Angle commands. 
The syntax for GeoGebra commands are:

```
Checkbox[ <Caption>, <List> ]
SetValue[ <Boolean|Checkbox>, <0|1> ]
Angle[ <Line>, <Line> ]
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, the syntax error you're running to is because of these lines of code:

```
function Set {
```

and after fixing this, `new function(index)` / `new function(object)` will also cause problems.

This isn't valid JS, you're likely looking for this:

```
function Set() {
  this.elements = [];
  this.size = 0;
}

Set.prototype.get = function(index) {
  return this.elements[index];
};

Set.prototype.add = function(object) {
  this.elements[this.size] = object;
  this.size = this.size + 1;
};
```

Notice no `new` before each `function` as well.

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish by creating this `Set` object though - it looks like a wrapper for holding an array and its size, similar to how something might be implemented in C.  In JavaScript, arrays can be mutated freely without worrying about memory.

Here's an untested refactor that removes the use of `Set` in favour of native JavaScript capabilities (mostly mutable arrays):

```
var names = ggbApplet.getAllObjectNames();
var lines = [];
var angles = [];
var groups = [];

for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
  if (getObjectType(names[i].e) === "line") {
    lines.push(names[i]);
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    angles.push(new Angle(i, j));
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < angles.length; i++) {
  var thisVal = angles[i].value;
  var placed = false;
  for (var j = 0; j < groups.length; j++) {
    if (groups[j][0].value === thisVal) {
      groups[j].push(angles[i]);
      placed = true;
    }
  }
  if (!placed) {
    groups.push([angles[i]]);
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
  var list = "";
  for (var j = 0; j < groups[i].length; j++) {
    list += groups[i][j].name;
    if (j != groups[i].length - 1) {
      list += ",";
    }
  }

  var comm1 = "Checkbox[angle_{" + groups[i][0].value + "},{" + list + "}]";
  ggbApplet.evalCommand(comm1);
  var comm2 = "SetValue[angle_{" + groups[i][0].value + "}+,0]";
  ggbApplet.evalCommand(comm2);
}

function Angle(i, j) {
  this.name = "angleA_" + i + "B_" + j;
  var comm3 = "angleA_" + i + "B_" + j + " = Angle[" + lines[i] + "," + lines[j] + "]";
  ggbApplet.evalCommand(comm3);

  var val = ggbApplet.getValue(this.name);
  if (val > 180) {
    val -= 180;
  }

  this.value = val;
  ggbApplet.setVisible(name, false);
}
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thank you for solving the problem! As you can see I'm a total beginner, but now my code works. Thank you!!!

Comment: @user2804125 I'm happy I could help!  We all have to start somewhere.  I'm trying to get into game programming myself, and it is *much* different than what I'm used to :)

Answer (score 1):

Your function definition is missing the parameter list after the function name.

Also, you're initializing the `elements` property to an undefined value. You need to initialize it to an empty array, so that the `add` method can set elements of it.

```
function Set() {
    this.elements=[];
    this.size=0;
}
```